# A Question about the Level Set of a Smooth Function

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Recently I have been entertaining functions with the following assumptions: assume $f \in C_c^\infty(\bar{\mathbb{R}^2_+})$ with support $A$ which intersects with the $x$-axis. Then we can write $\partial A = \Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2$, where $\Gamma_2$ overlaps the $x$-axis and $\Gamma_1$ is the rest of the boundary. Let us assume $\Gamma_1$ be a smooth curve diffeomorphic to $[0,1]$. Moreover, assume that there exists some $\delta_0 > 0$ such that for any $p \in \{x\;|\; dist(x,\Gamma_1) < \delta_0\}\cap A^\circ$, $p$ is a regular point in the sense that the gradient $\nabla f$ does not vanish at $p$. I would like to claim that: one can find some level $\epsilon > 0$ depending on $\delta_0$ such that there exists a subset $\Gamma$ of the level set $\{f = \epsilon\}$ such that 1. $\Gamma \subset \{x\;|\; dist(x,\Gamma_1) < \delta_0\}\cap A^\circ$, and 2. $\Gamma$ is a simple, smooth curve diffeomorphic to $[0,1]$ with its endpoints lying on the $x$-axis.

Intuitively I think this is true, as I see this curve $\Gamma$ as a perturbation of $\Gamma_1$. In fact, I believe that I have a scratch of the argument using the implicit function theorem. But I am afraid that my knowledge on geometry might be so insufficient that I might overlook some counterexamples. Can anyone take a look at the statement and see if the claim is true? Thanks in advance and any comment is appreciated! If people think that this claim works, I will provide my sketch of "proof" here.